# How to limit an array value between a certain range

Tags: c#

I want the values in the array to be between 1 & 100 because they’re grades for a test. How do I do this? Is it possible?

I’ve used a for loop to take in the contents of the array

Comment: Yes, check their value. If its above 100 or below 0, alter it to be within range.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Why would the process be different for an array value vs any other value?

Comment: Look for Primitive Obsession term. For example [Design Smell: Primitive Obsession](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/25/DesignSmellPrimitiveObsession/)

Answer (score 0):

Its quite easy to filter the array after the fact with LINQ. Then use only the validated grades

```cs
int[] rawGrades = {100, 87, 999};
int[] validGrades = rawGrades
    .Where(g => g <= 100 && g >=0)
    .ToArray(); // {100, 87}
```

Validating this upfront would be possible, but would lead to some potentially weird but valid nonetheless code. Off the top of my head I can imagine you make a `Grade` class, which will contain a `Score` property, wherein you can have your setter intervene

```cs
public class Grade
{
    private int _score;
    public int Score
    {
        get => _score;
        set => _score = value >= 0 && value <= 100 ? value : throw new ArgumentException("Grades must be from 0-100 inclusive");
    }
}

Grade[] grades = new Grade[];
grades[0] = new Grade { Score = 99 }; //valid
grades[1] = new Grade { Score = 99999 }; //invalid, will throw exception

//get the grades as int's with some LINQ also
int[] scores = grades.Select(g => g.Score).ToArray()
```

There is always the option of validating the input grade prior to it being added to the array, which is the simplest option

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, reframe it. What you need is something that represents a number from 1 to 100. Once you have that, you can put more than one in an array, list, etc.

The tendency is to use existing numeric types like `int`, `single`, `decimal`, etc. That can work, but as you've recognized there's always a risk that some code (or some person) will accidentally set a value that's out of range.

There's are different ways to create what you need. Here's just one:

```cs
public class TestScore
{
    public byte Score { get; }

    public TestScore(byte score)
    {
        if (score < 1 || score > 100)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
                $"{nameof(score)} must be in the range of 1 to 100.");
        }
        Score = score;
    }
}
```

`TestScore` is a class that contains a value `Score` and restricts what that value can be. You can't create an instance of `TestScore` without providing a valid value. Once the score is set, it can't be changed. That means if you have an instance of `TestScore`, it's guaranteed to have a valid score between 1 and 100.

Now you can put them in an array.

```cs
var testScores = new TestScore[5];
```

...or a list, or any other collection.

```cs
var testScores = new List<TestScore>();
```

I used `byte` because it uses less memory than `int` (only values from 0 to 255) but it's splitting hairs. It probably doesn't matter. If you wanted to have scores with decimal places (75.5) you could use `single`.

Or you might decide that the score should be represented as a number between 0 and 1, like 0.0, .75, or 1. In that case you could use a `single` and validate that it's >= 0 and <=1.

Comment: `decimal` is overkill for a floating type, that type has precision to handle monetary calculations but in everyday use, especially something as basic as grades, something like a `double` or `float`/`single` would suffice tbh. Not to mention OP would have to add the `m` suffix to everything if they did use decimal. You also are not wrong about using `byte` but personally I would just keep it as `int` for simplicity sake

Comment: You're right. I removed that.